# How to use pseudo classes in styled components?

Tags: reactjs

So as i mentioned in the title when i am using styled component, I want to use ::after in my input and it does not work.. I put my code right below, so check it out

```html
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Input = styled.input`
    padding: 25px 80px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    border: none;
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.grey};
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
        border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.main};
    }
    ::after {
        content: "hi"
    }
`;

export default Input;
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you? , if yes please accept my answer

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? A fiddle or snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in the following way:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const div = styled.div`
    padding: 25px 80px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    border: none;
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.grey};
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
        border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.main};
    }
    &:after {
        content: "hi"
    }
`;

export default Input;
```

**Input element doesn't allow the use of before and after pseudo classes**

Comment: Did my solution work for you? , if yes please **accept my answer**

Comment: No, I think the problem is, in input we can't have ::before or :;after

Comment: Yeah you were right we cannot have after and before for input, you can checkout this page for more info: https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2014/06/24/pseudo-element-input.html#:~:text=In%20case%20you%20weren't,be%20used%20on%20container%20elements.

Comment: I have edited the answer so that no one takes a wrong reference